# Cocoa-Touch Back Button with Tabbed Navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I am developing an iOS application that uses a left side slide out drawer containing tabs, each representing one of the main views of the app. Currently, when the user selects a tab the application searches through the navigation stack for an instance of the relevant view controller and if it finds one pops back to that controller, otherwise it creates a new instance and pushes it onto the stack.

I would like to also add a back button allowing the user to go back to the previous view, however since many navigation options will pop the user to a previous view controller resulting in the controller they are leaving being dealloc'ed there is no obvious way to have a back button to get back to that controller again.

Is there any way to structure this application so that a back button can be added, while still allowing the user to use the tabs to navigate to any view at a given time?

An example of the navigation code follows (invoked when a user clicks one of the tabs):

```
if(![self.navigation.topViewController isKindOfClass:[GraphViewController class]]) { //Are we already in this view?
    BOOL foundController = NO;
    for(id controller in self.navigation.viewControllers) { //Is there a controller of this type already in the stack?
        if([controller isKindOfClass:[GraphViewController class]]) {
            [self.navigation popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
            foundController = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!foundController) {
        GraphViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"graphViewController"];
        controller.connection = _connection;
        controller.data = _dataCache;
        [self.navigation pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is navigation controllers for each item in the slide out menu. This way when the user selects a view from the side menu they can navigate the views associated with that section. This will allow the user to go back from a view once they have selected a item from the side menu.

Comment: The problem is that each of the side menu items links to a single particular view in the app, and there are ways to get from one view to the others within the view themselves. I.E. Tab 1 links to A, Tab 2 links to B, A links to B, and A and B link to C. Each tab doesn't correspond to a discrete section.

Comment: Interesting, yea then this wont work. Hope someone else can chime in.